# SystemSound doesn't play on device (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, encoding, mp3

I'm currently developing an application for iPhone and I would like to play a sound when the user touch a button.

When I use a .mp3 audio file, the sound plays on the simulator but won't on the device.
When I use a .tif audio file, it plays on both of them, but the quality isn't really good.

So my question is, is it possible that my .mp3 isn't compressed in a good way ? How should I encode it to make it work on my device too ?
How to encode my mp3s in .tif with no quality loss ? (and without taking too much disk space)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want my honest opinion, stay away from using `SystemSound`.. you have no control over the audio at all (including volume level).  Instead, you should use an `AVAudioPlayer` detailed more in this prior post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128283/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-sound-quickly-upon-fast-button-presses-xcode/3129905#3129905

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer.
I finally converted my files into another format and all works very well now. I use .caf files and my code seems to work pretty well, no leaks and a very low memory usage.
SystemSound fits perfectly in this particular case because I didn't need to have control over at all levels, I just wanted to play some sounds whenever the user triggered some events.

Nevertheless, thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you use .aac format then it's decrease disk spaces,and you only increase the volume of the player.
if you specify using player then I help more about that.

Comment: You can't increase the volume of a `SystemSound`; this answer is just confusing to anyone other than those who already know about `AVAudioPlayer`.