# AVAudioPlayer doesn't work after 248 times

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer

I am developing an application that involves clicking a button repeatedly, and I am giving an audio feedback for this click, a click wave file.

it works fine, but I have a problem, after exactly 248 times, the sound is not played any more, the app doesn't crash however. and I get the following error:

***Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-43 "The operation couldn't be completed. (NSOSStatusErrorDomain error -43.)"***

here is the code I am using, (pretty standard)

```
//file.h
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;


//file.m
    NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"click" ofType:@"wav"];

        [audioPlayer stop]; //I added this in one of my trials to solve it.
        audioPlayer= [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]  error:&err];
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops=0;
        audioPlayer.delegate=self;
           [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];



        if (audioPlayer==nil)
            NSLog(@"%@, %@",path,[err description]);
        else
        [audioPlayer play];
```

any idea why this happens?

Comment: Create a sound file that's double the size and length (perhaps use an audio tool to double your existing clip) and experiment. Does the problem happen after 124 times? Also, what version of iOS are you targetting? What SDK do you have installed? What device are you testing on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've only ever seen that error message associated with streaming audio.  Might be something strange happening with the `NSURL` or...

Other issue with your code: When do you release the `audioPlayer` object?  If you aren't, you're allocating a lot of objects and never releasing them from memory.  That could eventually lead to a low memory message.

Another issue:  [Apple recommends](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767-CH2-SW28) using an IMA4 encoded *.caf file for playing multiple sounds at once

Lastly, I have posted a sample project from another question which might show a better way of using `AVAudioPlayer`  ...See this post [what is the best way to play sound quickly upon fast button presses xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128283/what-is-the-best-way-to-play-sound-quickly-upon-fast-button-presses-xcode/3129905#3129905)

Comment: You are correct, I didn't release the audioplayer correctly, and I didn't notice that earlier, but after you pointed that out, I checked my code again, and I fixed it.

now it works, thanks.